# При подключение JavaScript скрипта, не корректно работает JSP и HTML-страница

Tags: javascript, html, css, java-ee, jsp

Нашел в бесплатном доступе  [анимационный фон для страницы](http://bayguzin.ru/demo2014/kruglyashki/index_circle.html). Содержит в себе файлы JS, CSS. Подключил к своей JSP-странице. Сам по себе скрипт работает, кружочки летают на фоне, но случилась проблема: моя JSP-страница содержит форму, где пользователь может нажимать на radiobutton, выбирать что-то в выпадающем списке и т.д. То есть после подключения скрипта на это всё нажимаешь и ничего не происходит. При подключении скрипта на HTML-страницы, естественно, также, форма становится как-будто не активной. Сам скрипт брал  [отсюда](http://bayguzin.ru/main/skriptyi/fonyi-dlya-sajta/potryasayushhie-animaczionnyie-fonyi-dlya-sajta-v-formate-html-s-podklyucheniem-skriptov.html)

Вот моя JSP, к которой подключал скрипт:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>

    <title>Фоновый эффект - Кругляшки</title>
    <link href="../css/circle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="../../docs-assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="pixie"></canvas>

<form action="/SettingsHandlerServlet" method="get">

    <p>Выберите режим игры: </p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="modeAnswer" value="3" checked>3 x 3</input></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="modeAnswer" value="4">4 x 4</input></p>

    <p>Выберите сложность: </p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="lvlAnswer" value="11" checked>Цифры от 0 до 10</input></p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="lvlAnswer" value="21">Цифры от 0 до 20</input></p>

    <p>Время на запоминание цифр (в секундах): </p>
    <select name="timeAnswer">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>

    <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/parallaxsoon3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Файл CSS:

```css
/********* Canvas*************/
 body
 {
    background:url(../img/city.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; 
    -moz-background-size: 100%; 
    -o-background-size: 100%; 
    background-size: 100%; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
 #pixie{position:fixed;}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index....  добавь всем своим элементам  z-index именно тем элементам которые ты писал
или же

```
<canvas id="pixie" style="z-index:-1000;"></canvas>
```

или спусти canvas ниже своего кода в html

Comment: <canvas id="pixie" style="z-index:-1000;"></canvas>

Помогло!

А если canvas поставить за формой, то и скрипт работает за формой. То есть, кружки перемещаются только под формой

Comment: Да. Если вставить после </form>. Или имеется в виду вообще в самый низ?